# Help to prove that $ [D^{-1} + P_3D^{-1}(L+U)P_{2}D^{-1}(L+U)P_{1}D^{-1}(L+U) - D^{-1}L]*D^{-1} = (D+L)^{-1} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I know that the following statement is true but I cannot see how to prove it. I really appreciate if somebody could help. Thank you.

Let A be a 3x3, nonsingular matrix. Show that:

$$ [D^{-1} + P_3D^{-1}(L+U)P_{2}D^{-1}(L+U)P_{1}D^{-1}(L+U) - D^{-1}L]*D^{-1} = (D+L)^{-1} $$

where, 
$$P_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \quad P_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}  \quad P_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

and D, L, and U are the diagonal, lower triangular, and upper triangular matrices of matrix A, respectively.

UPDATE:

I simplified the original equation to: $$ DP_3D^{-1}LP_2D^{-1}LP_1D^{-1} = LD^{-1}LD^{-1} $$
by using properties of matrices and so on. I also verified it using numerical examples. However, I do not know how to further simplify the final equation. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the expression on the left of your matrix equation by $(D+L)$ and expanding/simplify using the properties of the given matrices?

Comment: @AnyAD The best I could get is $ D^{-1} + P_3D^{-1}LP_2D^{-1}LP_1D^{-1} - D^{-1}LD^{-1} = (D + L)^{-1}$

Comment: @AnyAD Actually if I multiply both sides by (D+L), I get to the correct equation. But I want to reach from the left side to the right side by expanding/simplifying...

Comment: What is $A$ in relation to all the other matrices (does not seem to appear anywhere)? Any other conditions?

Comment: ``Actually if I multiply both sides by (D+L), I get to the correct equation... " That does not make sense, as you can't assume obviously that the two are equal.

Comment: @AnyAD D, L, and U are are the diagonal, lower triangular, and upper triangular matrices of A. No other condition.

Comment: You should edit your question to include that information.

Comment: @AnyAD What I meant was that I could numerically verify the final equation after multiplying both sides by $(D+L)$. But I could not reach to a simplified equation. Here is what I got after simplification: $ DP_3D^{-1}LP_2D^{-1}LP_1D^{-1} = LD^{-1}LD^{-1} $

Comment: And explain what exactly you mean by `diagonal of $A$' etc. Diagonal matrix with $d_{ii}=a_{ii}$ etc

Comment: @AnyAD What do you mean by ``You should edit your question to include that information"? I have mentioned this information in the question.